# How to create predefined autocomplete like parameters for search query

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am creating a search field in the navigation to search for the content from database. In database I have a couple of entities like Products, Orders & Invoices.
I want the user to write the search term and then specify from which entity he wants this term to be searched against.

So use case is: User simply write the search term in the input field and there appears a autocomplete like box with predefined options:

> Search in 'Products'
>
> Search in 'Orders'
>
> Search in 'Invoices'

Then user manually selects a given option, and search term along with that selected parameter is sent to back-end for results processing.

Here is what I want the field to look like and behave
http://jsfiddle.net/wr1Lm6t5/

```
Search: <input type="text" />

$("input").autocomplete({
    source: ["Search in 'Products'", "Search in 'Orders'", "Search in 'Invoices'"],
    minLength: 0,
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

But the problem is upon selection of an autocomplete option search term is lost.

I can't use server-side processing with ajax and I don't want to spoil navigation with radio buttons.

Comment: You want to add single search for all?

Comment: I want to let the user decide where he want to search. Lets say he want to search for "Mobile", he should type the term and the auto-complete shows three options below it: search in Products, Invoices Or Orders. So that I can query to the appropriate entity accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event of autocomplete to get ajax

```
$("#parent").autocomplete({
source: [ { label: "Products", value: "Products" },{ label: "Invoices", value:"Invoices" },{ label: "Orders", value: "Orders" }],
    minLength: 0,

  change: parentChange
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

Will This Work For You? Check Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/83tbcnsz/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help Ravi, but my use case is a bit different here. Instead of having categorized json data already available (as you have shown in your working example), I want to send two parameters to back-end logic: 1) The search term itself. 2) the option from drop-down for the entity against which search would be performed. I have limitation so cant use Ajax to pre-populate data as json in autocomplete like you guided.

Comment: without ajax.. you can pass query string to page and load that page. (not good way)